# Retrieve data from wristband heart rate sensor to Android application by Bluetooth low energy connection

Tags: java, android, c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I need to get all data from LogBlock charateristic of bracelet device, after a bluethooth low energy connection.

Actually I get only few byte by logblock and not all data. Does anyone know how to syncronyze and buffering all data?

Below my bluethoot service after method call connect()

```
    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,int status) {
         if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            Log.i("deviceBT","onCharacteristicRead "+characteristic.toString());
            broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
        }

    }
   private void broadcastUpdate(final String action,final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
    final Intent intent = new Intent(action);
    if (UUID_HEART_RATE_MEASUREMENT.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {
        int flag = characteristic.getProperties();
        int format = -1;
        if ((flag & 0x01) != 0) {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT16;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT16.");
        } else {
            format = BluetoothGattCharacteristic.FORMAT_UINT8;
            Log.d(TAG, "Heart rate format UINT8.");
        }
        final int heartRate = characteristic.getIntValue(format, 1);
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Received heart rate: %d", heartRate));
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DATA, String.valueOf(heartRate));

    }
    else if (UUID_LOGBLOCK.equals(characteristic.getUuid())) {

         byte[] value = characteristic.getValue();
        }
```

Tnx in advance

**UPDATE**

I don't get any data from wristbend device, because I have sand init command to it by a C program.

Can any one know how to send soket of bluethoot java connection, to C program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to notifications ... When you read characteristics in sequence, you must be careful to set before all enables notifications and then make the first writing. If you do not respect this order will not be notified of any change even if we respect the code correctly and read times on individual characteristics.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the raw byte array (`GetValue`) instead of `getIntValue`

Comment: Hi, in UUID_LOGBLOCK condition, I make byte[] value = characteristic.getValue(); But i get only few byte

Comment: Do you have any way to confirm that the bracelet device is actually updating the characteristic?

Comment: Yes It store any change in accellerometer, Hart Rate atc on logblock on interval of 30 minute.

Comment: hmmm, onCharacteristicRead is regularly called then (for each characteristic update)?

Comment: yes on charateristicRead, I call a native C decompress method(it's a black box) by android, passing a characteristic.getValue() ,  and it return me only few byte. I parse this byte and get only accell value. So I'm thinking that i have to make a syncronyze meccanism for get all data by device

Comment: Ok - I just checked my code again, it's OnCharacteristicChanged you should be looking at. There should be no need to synchronize. Normally the timeline is that the remote BTLE device updates a characteristic , then your BluetoothGattCallback  OnCharacteristicChanged object is called, there you should have the latest data.

Comment: Hi, Yesterday, I set a fastest rate to device acquisition, and I get more data. The question is that, the device collect data in a Logblock eprom, when I connect to it with BLE, and I click on Logblock charateristic, it get data on eprom with charateristicRead. I'm not sure if i get all Eprom Data.

Comment: How I can gether data every time Logblock eprom si updated, without click on logblock charateristic by android app?

Comment: You must override OnCharacteristicChanged in your BluetoothGattCallback object. OnCharacteristicChanged will be call everytime there is an update

Comment: I think that problem not is on listener but on read state of wristband device. I think that I have to send start flag or download flag to device for reading logblock data. I'm trying with  //WED_CONFIG_LOG_DL_EN
                  bc.setValue(new byte[]{(byte) (1<<0)});
                     result = this.mBTGatt.writeCharacteristic(bc);
                     if (result) {
                         return result;
                     } but nothing happen...